# Is it possible to delete C POD using delete in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, types, delete-operator

Having structs like

```
struct ifoo_version_42 {
   int x, y, z;
   char *imageData;
};
```

where `imageData` is something like `imageData =  new char[50000];`

Can we perform something like:

```
template< typename T >
void del( T a ) // we promise to use this only on C Plain Old data structs=)
{
  delete a;
}
```

on this structure an will it be enough to clean memory form if?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting the struct does *not* recursively delete any pointers in it, and hence doesn't free the array of char pointed to by `imageData`.

I'm also a bit confused by your use of `delete[]`. You can free an array (allocated with `new[]`) using `delete[]`, or free a single object (allocated with `new`) using `delete`. You can't mix them, and you don't say how you're allocating one or more instances of `ifoo_version_42`. For example the following has undefined behavior:

```
ifoo_version_42 *x = new ifoo_version_42;
del(x);
```

The following is OK:

```
ifoo_version_42 *x = new ifoo_version_42[1];
del(x);
```

Comment: And so... how to make shure my struct is cleaned up?

Comment: If you insist on it being POD, then do it any of the ways that you would in C, probably write a `del_ifoo` function that takes a pointer to ifoo, and first frees the `imageData` then frees the ifoo. If you'd prefer to write idiomatic C++, then replace the `char*` with a `vector<char>`, and if you dynamically allocate an `ifoo` using `new` then immediately put the result into one of the smart pointers (which one depends how the caller intends to use it). You could also keep it POD and use `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter, the deleter function being the `del_ifoo` described above.

Comment: C++ memory management is (or can be) mostly about how to avoid calling `new`. If you don't call `new`, then you don't have to worry about who's going to call `delete`. Part of the point of `vector` is that it provides memory-managed arrays without the user having to explicitly free anything, so it's intended exactly for this job.

Answer (score 5):

This function template would also "work" on non-POD types.  It's literally no different from invoking `delete[] a;` directly.

However, this won't delete the memory associated with `imageData`.  That's typically the sort of thing you do in a destructor.

Comment: Structs have destructors? (sorry - I am C/C++ nube, and I am reading a book)

Comment: @Kabumbus: `struct` and `class` are essentially identical in C++ (except for whether members are public or private by default).  So yes, structs can have destructors.  But that would no longer be a POD.

Answer (score 3):

If you perform your `del` function on an `ifoo_version_42`, then the memory block pointed to by `data` will not be freed; neither `delete` nor `delete[]` work recursively.

`delete[]` is meant to be used for freeing `arrays`; that is, if you allocated `imageData` with `new[]`, then it should be freed with `delete[]`.

`delete` is meant to be used for freeing single objects: If you e.g. allocated a `ifoo_version_42` with `new`, then you should free it with `delete`.

(Also, never use `delete` for something allocated with `malloc()`, or `free()` with something allocated with `new`.)

One further suggestion: [Learn the RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and use smart pointer classes provided by the STL or Boost libraries; these go a long way towards helping you with correct memory management.

Comment: Or even even better, use a vector ;-)

Comment: (@Steve, agreed, but I was talking about the general case, not the `ifoo_version_42` in particular.)